# Send Message from Chrom extension to Launch Agent Mac

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, launch-agent

Is it possible to send message from chrome extension to a launch agent or to a daemon in mac ?

Comment: See `nativeMessaging` API.

Comment: nativeMessaging spawns a new process everytime but In my case I need to connect to already running launch agent.
I am now trying to use WebServer socket to achieve this .
I will update my results here. 
Thank you